# Bundle disappearing from fragment after commit?

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I have an Activity whose sole purpose to to host a fragment. I'm starting this activity with an Intent, then using information from the Intent to add args to a Fragment which I'd like to add to the new Activity.

Here is the onCreate in SingleClickerActivity (this Activity is started by the Intent). When stepping through this I have verified that the fragment has the argument I want to send. [Fragment has argument (this is right before the transaction step)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZCIQ.png)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResId());

    UUID clickerId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CLICKER_ID);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment(clickerId);
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

I've made the fragment, it has the args bundle, and I commit it. However, when I get to the fragment's onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mClickerId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_CLICKER_ID);
    mClicker = ClickerBox.get(getActivity()).getClicker(mClickerId);
}
```

`getArguments()` returns null. The bundle has poofed. Where is it getting lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The `onCreate` method called its super, which created another fragment with no arguments. I was getting two fragments, one with args and one without. The empty one was the one getting attached to the activity. I took out the `onCreate` in `SingleClickerActivity` so that I'd be using the inherited version, then moved the line `UUID clickerId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_CLICKER_ID); into createFragment().`